# Github Pages/Jekyll Blog won't update

Tags: git, jekyll, github-pages

My blog is at: http://nolls1.github.io/WiFi-RC-Truck/

I just created it today and was writing my first post, and it was updating up until a certain point. Now, even though my changes are reflected in my repository when I commit the changes, it won't update on the actual page (the link above). I am not using the command line, so I am working with it using the GUI on github. Anyone have any idea what can be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you have a build error. Github sends emails about build errors. Check your inbox, or build locally to see the error.